# can a class extend a service and be instantiated with new keyword in angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, extends, angular2-services, angular2-http

Hi I have a Service like

```
@Injectable()
export class ParentService{

  constructor(private http:Http){}

  get(){this.http.get(...)}
}
```

can I create a class which extends the service? e.g.

```
export class SomeClass extends ParentService {
  public name:string;
  constructor(name:string, private http:Http){
    super(http);
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

and use the **new** keyword to instantiate inside a component like

```
export class Cmp{
  instance:any;
  constructor(){
    this.instance = new SomeClass('InstanceOne', ?? )
    this.instance.get();
  }
}
```

The idea is that with each new instance I can pass a string as urlPath and use that instance to call generic functions from my service. Thanks!

Comment: I guess you can. Have you tried that? Do you have problems with this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want DI to pass a constructor parameter, then you need to delegate instantiation to Angulars DI.

What you can do is

```
export class Cmp{
  instance:any;
  constructor(http:Http){
    this.instance = new SomeClass('InstanceOne', http);
    this.instance.get();
  }
}
```

Or alternatively you can provide a string and use `@Inject('sometoken')` to get `name` passed in by DI when it creates a new `SomeClass`.

Comment: this works great, thanks! If I instantiate a new SomeClass, do I actually instantiate a new javescript object including the properties and methods of ParentService?